# Mapping multiple functions over an array

Tags: map, list-manipulation

I am looking for an elegant way to Map multiple functions over an array. My problem looks something like this:

Consider a list of functions:

```
f = {f1,f2,f3,f4} (* example, can be larger *)
```

And an array:

```
A = {{a1, b1, c1, d1, e1}, {a2, b2, c2, d2, e2}, {a3, b3, c3, d3, e3}}; (*example, can be larger*)
```

**Q1:** I’d like to map the functions in f over the array A so that the final result looks like:

```
B= {{1 - a1, f1[a1]*b1, f2[a1]*c1, f3[a1]*d1, f4[a1]*e1}, {1 - a2, 
f1[a2] b2, f2[a2] c2, f3[a2] d2, f4[a2] e2}, {1 - a3, f1[a3] b3, 
f2[a3] c3, f3[a3] d3, f4[a3] e3}}
```

[image: Sample input/output]

**Q2:**  How do I map the functions a little differently so that the output looks like:

```
c= {{a1, f1[a1] b1, f2[b1] c1, f3[c1] d1, f4[d1] e1}, {a2, f1[a2] b2, 
f2[b2] c2, f3[c2] d2, f4[d2] e2}, {a3, f1[a3] b3, f2[b3] c3, 
f3[c3] d3, f4[d3] e3}} // tf
```

[image: Alternate mapping]

Comment: Just writing it out `func[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := {1 - a, b f1[a], c f2[a], d f3[a], e f4[a]}` and then `func/@A` is pretty elegant, I think.

Comment: The issue is that the array sizes and functions I show are examples and in reality the arrays/functions are quite large so writing it out gets pretty tedious…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to write out the map concisely:

#### Q1:

```
{1 - #, ##2} Through[Join[{1 &}, f]@#] & @@@ A
(* {{1 - a1, b1 f1[a1], c1 f2[a1], d1 f3[a1], e1 f4[a1]}, 
    {1 - a2, b2 f1[a2], c2 f2[a2], d2 f3[a2], e2 f4[a2]}, 
    {1 - a3, b3 f1[a3], c3 f2[a3], d3 f3[a3], e3 f4[a3]}} *)
```

#### Q2:

```
Join[{1 - #[[1]]}, MapThread[#3 #@#2 &, {f, Most@#, Rest@#}]] & /@ A
(* {{1 - a1, b1 f1[a1], c1 f2[b1], d1 f3[c1], e1 f4[d1]}, 
    {1 - a2, b2 f1[a2], c2 f2[b2], d2 f3[c2], e2 f4[d2]}, 
    {1 - a3, b3 f1[a3], c3 f2[b3], d3 f3[c3], e3 f4[d3]}} *)
```

Comment: Holy crap… never knew there was a function called Through… this is brilliant!

Comment: Any take on Q2 above?

Comment: BTW, brilliant @rm-rf.

Comment: @Pam See edit... there probably are other ways, but this does the job.

Answer (score 4):

I was thinking about a more readable way because your question under rm's answer

> Any take on Q2 above?

slightly indicates that you couldn't take it further although the idea to solve Q2 was similar. I guess my solution is in no way as easy as I had hoped it to be, but I give it anyway.

What it does is that it separates the tasks a bit. The `distributor` takes your list of functions and exactly one sublist like e.g. `{a1, b1, c1, d1, e1}` and builds up the result. For your Q1 this is just calculating `1-a1` and creating all the `x1*fn[a1]`.

```
distributor[funcs_][vec_] :=
 Join[{1 - First[vec]}, #2*#1[First[vec]] & @@@ Transpose[{funcs, Rest[vec]}]
  ]
```

And now you can map the `distributor` over your `A`

```
distributor[f] /@ A
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

To solve your second problem Q2 you only need to adjust the `distributor` which now includes a call to `Partition` to create sequence `{{a1, b1}, {b1, c1}, {c1, d1}, {d1, e1}}` we need:

```
distributor2[funcs_][vec_] :=
 Join[{1 - First[vec]}, #2[[2]]*#1[#2[[1]]] & @@@ Transpose[{funcs, Partition[vec, 2, 1]}]
  ]

distributor2[f] /@ A
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is a very nice answer as well.